# Is a neural network a lazy or eager learning method?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

Is a neural network a lazy or eager learning method?  Different web pages say different things so I want to get a solid answer with good literature to back it up.  The most obvious book to look in would be Mitchell's famous Machine Learning book but skimming through the whole thing I can't see the answer.  Thanks :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the definition of the terms [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_learning) and [eager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_learning) learning, and knowing how a neural network works, I believe that it is clear that it is *eager*.  A trained network *is* a generalisation function, all the weights and paths used to arrive at a classification are entirely determined by training data, but the training data itself is not retained for the purposes of the decision making.

An important distinction is that a Lazy system stores its training data and uses it directly to determine a solution.  An eager system determines a function from the *training* data, and thereafter the training data is no longer required.  That is to say you cannot determine what the training data was from an eager system's function. A neural network certainly fits that description.  An eager system can therfore be very storage efficient, but conversely is non-deterministic, in the sense that it is not possible to determine how or why it arrived a a particular solution, so problems of poor or inappropriate training data may be difficult deal with.

The eager article linked above even gives artificial neural networks as an example.  You might of course prefer a cited text to Wikipedia but the page has existed with that assertion since 2007 without contradictory edits, so I'd say that was pretty robust.

Comment: I'm not sure this is always true. Looking at this wikipedia article[1] it looks like neural network is a pretty general term.  It may be true that most neural networks are eager (and there are good space saving reasons for this as you mention).  Are you working from a particular definition of neural network? (1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network)

Comment: @olleicua : I am not sure how the link supports your argument.  Given that you concede that *most* neural networks are eager, perhaps you should specify the definition *you* are referring rather that requiring me to do so (5 years after the event).  Predictor gives an answer below suggesting networks that are *lazy*, but that assertion was disputed by Igor quite plausibly.

Comment: My definition (until I find a reason not to use it) is the one on wikipedia. That definition states no requirement that it be eager.  Perhaps you misunderstand my argument.  I'm not claiming that neural networks aren't typically eager.  I'm claiming that they don't necessarily have to be eager.  I'm bringing this up now because I found it now and it is still the accepted answer in a public forum where people are likely to find and believe it.  I'm pointing out that you lack the evidence to support your claim and suggesting you use the weaker claim: "most artificial neural networks are eager".

Comment: @olleicua : I fail to find the "definition" in the text that supports your argument. Perhaps you should quote the specific text? I arrived at my conclusion by consideration of the nature of ANNs and eager/lazy learning, and presented my arguments clearly rather than simply stating one way or another without support.  It is at best an opinion, and must be taken with the supporting argument to come to your own view. This question should probably have been close d as off topic for SO and if asked today, probably would be.

Answer (score 3):

Some neural networks are eager learners, and some are lazy.  Feedforward neural networks (as are commonly trained by some variant of backpropagation) are eager: they attempt to derive a representation of the underlying relationships in the data at the time of training.  Radial basis function networks (such as probabilistic NN or generalized regression NN), on the other hand, are lazy learners (very much like k-nearest neighbors, the classic lazy learner).

Comment: I'd consider RBF networks to be eager learners, too. The positions of basis centers and the weights are computed ***before*** recall.

Answer (score 1):

A neural network is generally considered to be an "eager" learning method.

"Eager" learning methods are models that learn from the training data in real-time, adjusting the model parameters as new examples are presented. Neural networks are an example of an eager learning method because the model parameters are updated during the training process, as the algorithm iteratively processes the training examples. This allows the model to adapt and improve its performance as more examples are seen.

On the other hand, "lazy" learning methods, also known as instance-based or memory-based learning, only learn from the training data when a new example is presented. The model does not update its parameters during the training process but instead, it memorizes the training data and uses it to make predictions. Lazy learning methods typically require less computation time to make predictions than eager learning methods, but they may not perform as well on unseen data.

In general, neural networks are considered eager learning methods because their parameters are updated during the training process.

Here are a few literature references:

1. "Eager Learning vs. Lazy Learning" by R. S. Michalski, J. G. Carbonell, and T. M. Mitchell. This paper provides a comprehensive overview of the distinction between eager and lazy learning, and discusses the strengths and weaknesses of each approach. It was published in Machine Learning, 1983.
2. "An overview of instance-based learning algorithms" by A. K. Jain and R. C. Dubes. This book chapter provides an overview of the main concepts and techniques used in instance-based or lazy learning, and compares them to other types of learning algorithms, such as decision trees and neural networks. It was published in "Algorithms for Clustering Data" by Prentice-Hall, Inc. in 1988.
3. " Machine Learning" by Tom Mitchell. This book provides a comprehensive introduction to the field of machine learning, including the concepts of eager and lazy learning. It covers a wide range of topics, from supervised and unsupervised learning to deep learning and reinforcement learning. It was published by McGraw-Hill Education in 1997.
4. "Introduction to Machine Learning" by Alpaydin, E. This book provides an introduction to the field of machine learning, including the concepts of eager and lazy learning, as well as a broad range of machine learning algorithms. It was published by MIT press in 2010

It's also worth noting, that this classification of lazy and eager learning is not always clear cut and can be somewhat subjective, and some algorithms can belong to both categories, depending on the specific implementation.